# How to exit a program when using blocking calls

Tags: multithreading, sockets, destructor, exit, blocking

I need to do a project where the application monitors incoming connections and apply some rules as defined in a xml document. The rules are either filtering (blocking or permitting) connections or redirect traffic on a certain port. In order to do this, I use functions such as accept and recv (from Winsock). All of those functions are used on different threads. I'm wondering, though, how am I supposed to clean up the program before exiting since all those blocking calls are made. Normally I'd either wait until the person exits the console through the X button or waiting for the user to input a certain character in the main thread. The thing is I'm not sure what happens if the application exits while there are still active threads/if memory is still allocated/ if sockets are in use. Are all destructors called? Are h andles and sockets correctly closed? Or do I need to somehow do it myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I would say no.  Do not try to explicitly clean up resources like sockets, fd's, handles, threads unless you are absolutely forced to.

Exact behaviour depends on OS and how you terminate your app.

All the common desktop OS will release resources allocated to a process by the OS when a process terminates.  This includes sockets, file descriptors, memory.

On Windows/Linux, if you return from your C/C++ main() without any explicit cleanup, static dtors will get called by the crt code.  Dtors for dynamically allocated objects in non-main threads are not run.

Executables written in other languages may behave differently.

If, instead of returning from main(), you call a 'ProcessExit()' API directly, static destructors will not get called because the OS has no concept of dtors - it has no idea, or interest, in what language was used to generate the executable.

In either case, the OS will be called to terminate your process.  The OS does this, (simple 'Dummies' version:), by first changing the state of all process threads that are not running so that they never run again.  Threads that are running on other cores are then stopped.  Then OS resources like fd, sockets are closed, then released, then all process memory is freed, then OS kernel process/thread objects freed, then your process no longer exists.

If you absolutely need some, or all, C++/whatever dtors called when some thread needs to stop the app, you will have to explcitly signal other threads to stop so that dtors can be run.  I tend to use a globally-accessible 'CloseRequested' bool that relevant blocking calls check immediately after returning. There remains the issue of persuading the blocking calls to return.

Some blocking calls can be coded up to wait on more than one signal, so allowing the call to return by a simple event/sema/condvar/whatever signal.

Some calls, like recv(), accept(), can be pesuaded to return early by closing the fd/socket they are waiting on.

Some calls can be made to return by 'artificially' satisfying their wait condition - eg. creating a temp file just to make a folder-monitor call return so that the 'CloseRequested' bool can be checked.

If a blocking call is so annoyingly stubborn that it cannot be persuaded to return, you could redesign your app so that whatever the critical resource is that is released in the dtors can be released by another thread - maybe create the thing in another thread and pass it to the thread that blocks in a ctor parameter, something like that.

NOTE WELL:  Thread shutdown code bodges, as listed above, are extra code that does not add to the normal functionality of your app.  You should restrict explicit thread shutdown to those threads that hold resources that absolutely must be released by explicit user code - DB connections, say.  If the OS can release the resource, it should be allowed to do so.  The OS is very good at stopping all process threads before releasing resources they are using, user code is not.

Answer (score 0):

Where possible, use blocking calls that take a timeout value, and have your threads loop. That gives you a place to check for a shutdown condition and exit the thread gracefully. Handles will generally be cleaned up by the system when the process exits. It is polite to shut down sockets gracefully, but not absolutely mandatory.  The downside of not doing so is it can take a while for the kernel to clean up exclusive resources.  For example, if you just kill a thread waiting to accept(), and then your app re-launches, it won't be able to successfully accept() on the same port until the kernel cleans up the old socket.